# XSD schema accepting choice of 3 elements (strictly one time) and other two optional elements which may follow in any order

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing a schema that I would like to define the following structures (assume we have types `A, B, C, D, E`). The schema should accept one of `[A, B or C]` which must appear and appear only 1 time + one of `[D or E]` which might appear either single or both or none of both but not more than one time each. Both `ABC` and `DE` classes' elements should be insensitive to the order they follow. In other words the following examples are accepted:

```
<root>
    <el_A/>
</root>

<root>
    <el_B/>
    <el_E/>
    <el_D/>
</root>

<root>
    <el_C/>
    <el_D/>
</root>
```

And here are few examples of what the schema should not accept:

```
<root>
    <el_A/>
    <el_B/>
    <el_E/>
    <el_D/>
</root> 

<root>
    <el_C/>
    <el_D/>
    <el_D/>
</root>
```

My type defined for root looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:element name="el_A" type="tns:A"/>
            <xs:element name="el_B" type="tns:B"/>
            <xs:element name="el_C" type="tns:C"/>
        </xs:choise>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="el_D" type="tns:D" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="el_E" type="tns:E" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="el_E" type="tns:E" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="el_D" type="tns:D" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="el_E" type="tns:E"/>
            <xs:element name="el_D" type="tns:D"/>
        </xs:choise>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However when validating the documen against this schema the processor reports "cos-nonambig" error for `el_D`. I cannot understand why this schema allows ambigous interpretation since this describe a choise among three elements: either both exist in `DE` order, or both exist in `ED` order or only `E` exist or only `D` exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xsd can be simplified. I have attached the following variant:

```
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="el_A" type="tns:A"/>
                <xs:element name="el_B" type="tns:B"/>
                <xs:element name="el_C" type="tns:C"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xsd:group ref="el_E_el_D"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  <xs:group name="el_E_el_D">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="el_D" type="tns:D" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="el_E" type="tns:E" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:group>
```

Comment: This will not accept my second example since sequences specify the order in whicn the elemens should come.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It did not cover the case when E and D could appear in any order so I have fixed that. I think in your case would be useful to make use group element to define a group of elements to be used in complex type definitions. I have edited the attached scheme.